# Python Selenium - Data not visible; no error

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to scrape data from a website using Selenium, I am able to send values but not receiving the result to start scraping. The program is also not throwing any errors. Here's the reproducible code:

```
# Setting up driver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='D:\Program Files\ChromeDriver\chromedriver.exe')

# Opening up the webpage
driver.get("https://www1.nseindia.com/products/content/derivatives/equities/historical_fo.htm")

# Setting the value of Select Instrument
driver.find_element_by_id('instrumentType').send_keys('Index Options')

# Setting the value of Select Symbol
driver.find_element_by_id('symbol').send_keys('NIFTY 50')

# Setting the value of Select Year
driver.find_element_by_id('year').send_keys('2019')

# Setting the value of Select Expiry
select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('expiryDate'))
noOfExpiries = 2
select.select_by_index(noOfExpiries)

# Setting the value of Select Option Type
cycle = 'PE'
driver.find_element_by_id('optionType').send_keys(cycle)

# Clicking the date range radio button
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='rdDateToDate']").click()

# Setting the date range
fromDate = (datetime.strptime(select.options[noOfExpiries].text, '%d-%m-%Y') - timedelta(days=45)).strftime("%d-%b-%Y")
driver.find_element_by_id('fromDate').send_keys(fromDate)

toDate = datetime.strptime(select.options[noOfExpiries].text, '%d-%m-%Y').strftime("%d-%b-%Y")
driver.find_element_by_id('toDate').send_keys(toDate)

print(fromDate, toDate)

# Clicking the Get Data button
driver.find_element_by_id('getButton').click()
```

[image]

Any clue as to what am I missing here?

Comment: You do not scraped anything from the site after you click.

Comment: I receive no element to scrape data from after clicking "Get Data"

Comment: I see no delays inside the code. Did you define implicit wait timeout?

Comment: Yes, delay isn't an issue.

Comment: You can get the content from that site using requests module. Did you try that?

Comment: Haven't tried the `requests` module yet, but sure I will give that a try soon if this doesn't work out. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, this should do it. I came up with selenium based solution only because you expressed disinterest in requests module:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver import ChromeOptions
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')

with webdriver.Chrome(options=options) as driver:
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver,10)

    driver.get("https://www1.nseindia.com/products/content/derivatives/equities/historical_fo.htm")
    wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "instrumentType"))).send_keys('Index Options')
    wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "symbol"))).send_keys('NIFTY 50')
    wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "year"))).send_keys('2019')
    select = Select(wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "expiryDate"))))
    noOfExpiries = 13
    select.select_by_index(noOfExpiries)
    cycle = 'PE'

    wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "optionType"))).send_keys(cycle)
    item = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='rdDateToDate']")))
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();",item)
    fromDate = (datetime.strptime(select.options[noOfExpiries].text, '%d-%m-%Y') - timedelta(days=45)).strftime("%d-%b-%Y")
    wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "fromDate"))).send_keys(fromDate)

    toDate = datetime.strptime(select.options[noOfExpiries].text, '%d-%m-%Y').strftime("%d-%b-%Y")
    wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "toDate"))).send_keys(toDate,Keys.ENTER)

    print(fromDate, toDate)
    search_button = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "getButton")))
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();",search_button)
    tabular_content = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#historicalData > table"))).get_attribute("innerHTML")
    print(tabular_content)
```

Comment: Thanks for the fix and even improving the code quality!